# Typescript file being send to client with javascript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript  and trying to make a small application in visual studio 2013, however when i see the project in developer tools  of chrome i can see typescript files(*.ts) being downloaded to client, since this will only increase the download  size, is there any way  i can prevent it from being sent to client? I am using visual studio 2013.
[Image showing TS file in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErS9a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is being sent as `sourceMap`. You can disable this using *tsconfig* or *project properties* depending upon how the project is setup.